# MATLAB Sort 2D and 3D matrix and access through index

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, indexing

Let's said you have a 1D matrix

```
a = rand(1,5);
[sa i] = sort(a);
```

then `sa` and `a(i)` are the same. However, if the size of the matrix increases

```
a = rand(3,4);
[sa i] = sort(a);
```

then `sa` and `a(i)` are not the same. And the same happens when I'm trying to sort a 3D matrix by its third dimension.

How can I access the values of `a` through the index `i`? Or in other words how can I compute the `sa=a(X)`, what `X` should be?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the solutions. However, they don't work when you change the dimension to sort by. Nevertheless, I pick up the idea and use it to build a general form.

What the algorithm is doing is to build the indexes of the matrix. MATLAB index the cells column wise. Therefore, the index is given by

```
idx = r + (c-1)*ROWS + (p-1)*ROWS*COLS
```

where, `idx` is the index, `r` is the row position, `c` is the column position, and `p` is the page position.

Therefore, if we sort in the first dimension (normal `sort(a)`) the result index is the position in the columns; if we sort in the second dimension, the result index is the position in the rows; and if we sort in the third dimension, the result index is the page position. This being said, it only last to produce the rows and cols for the given case:

```
r = repmat((1:rows)',[1 cols pages]);
c = repmat(1:cols,[rows 1 pages]);
```

Sorting in the first dimension is explained in the solutions given. Then, lets sort in the second dimension (row wise) of a two dimensional array

```
a = rand(4,5);
[rows cols pages] = size(a);
R = repmat((1:rows)',[1 cols pages]);
[sa idx] = sort(a,2);
nIdx = R + (idx-1)*rows;
isequal(sa,a(nIdx))
```

Now, if we use the same idea for sorting in the third dimension (page wise), we need to do

```
a = rand(4,5,3);
[rows cols pages] = size(a);
R = repmat((1:rows)',[1 cols pages]);
C = repmat(1:cols,[rows 1 pages]);
[sa idx] = sort(a,3);
nIdx = R + (C-1)*rows + (idx-1)*rows*cols;
isequal(sa,a(nIdx))
```

And the same logic can be used to extend it to N dimensions.
Thanks for your help, you en light the way. :)

Comment: The best answer for 2D and 3D is right here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[sa, i]=sort(a)` returns the ordered indices for each column. You just need to get the correct linear indices for the matrix. So, for a 2D matrix,

```
A=rand(3,4);
[rows,cols]=size(A);
[B,index]=sort(A,1);
correctedIndex=index+repmat(0:cols-1,rows,1)*rows;
```

Now test it:

```
A =

    0.9572    0.1419    0.7922    0.0357
    0.4854    0.4218    0.9595    0.8491
    0.8003    0.9157    0.6557    0.9340

B =

    0.4854    0.1419    0.6557    0.0357
    0.8003    0.4218    0.7922    0.8491
    0.9572    0.9157    0.9595    0.9340

A(correctedIndex)

ans =

    0.4854    0.1419    0.6557    0.0357
    0.8003    0.4218    0.7922    0.8491
    0.9572    0.9157    0.9595    0.9340
```

Comment: In addition, you can also look into the `sortrows` function, whose second output argument can be used to achieve something like `sa=a(i,:)`, using your notation.

Comment: Thanks, you put me in the right direction. I get it how to work with the indexes. I extend your solution so it works for sorting in any dimension. thx

Answer (score 2):

You can create a general vectorized solution that will work for any N-D matrix or sort dimension by using the functions [IND2SUB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ind2sub.html) and [SUB2IND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html). Here, I've packaged this solution up into a new function `sort_linear_index`, which will behave just like the function [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) except that it will return linear indices so that `B = A(IX)` will always work no matter what size `A` is.

```
function [sortedA,sortIndex] = sort_linear_index(A,sortDim,sortOrder)
%#SORT_LINEAR_INDEX   Just like SORT, but returns linear indices

  sizeA = size(A);  %# Get the matrix size
  if nargin < 2
    sortDim = find(sizeA > 1,1);  %# Define sortDim, if necessary
  end
  if nargin < 3
    sortOrder = 'ascend';  %# Define sortOrder, if necessary
  end
  [sortedA,sortIndex] = sort(A,sortDim,sortOrder);  %# Sort the matrix
  [subIndex{1:numel(sizeA)}] = ...  %# Create a set of matrix subscripts
     ind2sub(sizeA,reshape(1:prod(sizeA),sizeA));
  subIndex{sortDim} = sortIndex;  %# Overwrite part of the subscripts with
                                  %#   the sort indices
  sortIndex = sub2ind(sizeA,subIndex{:});  %# Find the linear indices

end
```

And now we can test the function out:

```
>> A = rand(1,10);
>> [B,IX] = sort_linear_index(A);  %# Sort a row vector
>> isequal(B,A(IX))
ans =
     1
>> A = rand(3,4,3);
>> [B,IX] = sort_linear_index(A,1);  %# Sort a 3-by-4-by-3 matrix along
>> isequal(B,A(IX))                  %#   the first dimension
ans =
     1
>> [B,IX] = sort_linear_index(A,3);  %# Sort a 3-by-4-by-3 matrix along
>> isequal(B,A(IX))                  %#   the third dimension
ans =
     1
>> [B,IX] = sort_linear_index(A,2,'descend');  %# Sort a 3-by-4-by-3 matrix along
>> isequal(B,A(IX))                            %#   the second dimension
ans =                                          %#   in descending order
     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = rand(3,5);
[sa i] = sort(a);
ii=bsxfun(@plus,i,0:size(a,1):numel(a)-size(a,1));
isequal(a(ii),sa)
```

Answer (score 0):

from here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html

```
sa(:,j) = a(i(:,j),j)
```

Comment: Yes, I went around using the loop operation. However, I was wondering if there was some trick using just matrix operations or index, 'cause they are faster.