# How to get the indices of max values in a matrix,and map them to the indices of another same sized matrix?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, indices

I have two 16x12 matrices, In matrix A, I should sort in descending order and find the first 10 max values. But I should know the max values' indices before being sorted.

Finally, I should give those indices to the second matrix and find the values in that matrix.

I tried with for-loop but it doesn't give me accurate answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB Sort 2D and 3D matrix and access through index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643614/matlab-sort-2d-and-3d-matrix-and-access-through-index)

Comment: similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112677/find-sorting-index-per-row-of-a-2d-matrix-in-matlab-and-populate-a-new-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
[~,I] = sort(A(:), 'descend');
vals = B(I(1:10));
```

For example:

```
>> A = [ 4 2; 1 5];
>> B = [ 7 8; 0 NaN];
>> [~,I] = sort( A(:), 'descend' );
>> vals = B(I(1:2))

vals =
  NaN
  7
```

Comment: That's perfect. but what if my B matrix has NaN values?

Comment: In that case, NaN values are returned. What's the issue with that? What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking forward to the review privileges :)

Comment: I meant how I can skip NaN values in matrix B? I applied a zero mask to be substituted instead of them. Since they are background pixel of image

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand exactly: is `vals = vals(~isnan(vals));` what you need? In the example above, you'd get the array `vals = [7]` as an output.